# Rename a grid in acumatica using event row selected

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, acumatica

I tried to rename the display name in acumatica using this code below

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName<BOMMaterial.qtys>(this.MaterialDetail.Cache, "test");
```

and

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName(this.Caches[typeof(BOMMaterial)], typeof(BOMMaterial.qtys).Name , "test");
```

It does work if I put the code outside the event, so it will change when the screen is loaded. However, if I put it inside rowselected event and use validation, it doesn't change the display name. And it doesn't show any error.

Comment: Try changing `this.MaterialDetail.Cache` or `this.Caches[typeof(BOMMaterial)]` to the `PXCache` object which is passed to the event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set `RepaitColumns` property to `True` of `PXGrid` Control as well.

[image]